# Are any top-level domain lookups slower or less reliable than others?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

I'm creating an API for a potentially heavily trafficked web app. There is talk of using one of those less common domains such as .io or .ly. Are DNS lookups on these less common domains any slower or less reliable than others?

I'm guessing they're the same, it's just that some of the registrars for these domains seem kind of sketchy.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Why .io or .ly? Vanity or "coolness" factor? Why not use .com or .net?

Comment: thanks joe- A bit of both I suppose. .com and .net are also very hard to come by.

Comment: bit.ly doesn't seem to have an issue.

Comment: @TheCleaner good point, my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching happens at so many different levels in the DNS, that any performance difference between the TLDs is going to be negligible.

Regarding sketchy registrars? Well - I'd suggest finding a non-sketchy registrar.

Comment: Trying to put some numbers to "negligible": The worst case scenario as far as I can see is up to a few hundred milliseconds roughly every two days for each recursive resolver in use.  I concur with your assertion that there are better places to begin performance tuning.

Comment: Many thanks gentlemen. I'll not worry about this for now. Cheers